# Pandas loc automatically converting datetime to long

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have two datetime columns in a pandas dataframe: time_col & override_col. If override_col isn't null I want to replace the corresponding time_col record with the override_col record. The following code does this but it converts the override_col records to a long and not a datetime... then the time_col is a mix of datetime and long dtypes.

```
df.loc[~df['override_col'].isnull(), 'time_col'] =  df[~df['override_col'].isnull()]['override_col']
```

Any ideas why this is happening?!

Comment: could you attach part of your columns?

Comment: I actually solved the problem. The time_col dtype was set as object even though all the records were datetime. All I had to do is add pd.to_datetime (df['time_col']) prior to line above and it worked.